# Is "a -> b -> (a -> b -> c) -> c" to apply two parameters a standard functional concept?

Tags: f#, functional-programming, pipeline, partial-application, pipelining

I came across the need for a function with the signature `'a -> 'b -> ('a -> 'b -> 'c) -> 'c` to use for applying two arguments when piping:

```
let apply2 x y f =
  f x y
```

I needed this because I am using a function

```
myFun : MyType -> TypeA -> TypeB -> ResultType
```

and I use it in another function like this:

```
let useCase someValue (valueA: TypeA) (valueB: TypeB) =
  someValue
  |> ...
  |> toMyType
  |> myFun
  |> apply2 valueA valueB
```

`apply2` fits the bill, but I can't shake the feeling that I could use a built-in function or operator or that I am missing some more fundamental way of doing this (barring lambdas, which IMHO reads worse in this case). Note that I can't easily switch the parameter order of `myFun` (it's a Giraffe `HttpHandler`, so the last two parameters have to be `HttpFunc` and `HttpContext`, designated by `TypeA` and `TypeB` above).

Is the `apply2` function with the signature I've described a fair thing to use in functional programming, or am I missing something obvious? If this is a well-known concept, does it have a better name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my opinion the code is much clearer if you bind the intermediate value with `let`.

```
let useCase someValue (valueA: TypeA) (valueB: TypeB) =
    let myValue =
        someValue
        |> ...
        |> toMyType
    myFun myValue valueA valueB
```

You can also use backward pipes as follows

```
let useCase someValue (valueA: TypeA) (valueB: TypeB) =
    someValue
    |> ...
    |> toMyType
    |> myFun <| valueA <| valueB
```

Comment: Accepted for suggesting that it might be more readable to just use a simple intermediate value (in addition to suggesting a way to pipe it). As for the actual piping syntax, the other answers also have good suggestions.

Comment: Note that using the backwards pipe operator like that can be confusing as it becomes difficult to discern what is actually happening in that last line. Don Syme (the creator of F#) advises caution when using that operator and *never* using it in the same line of code with the forward pipe for that reason.

Comment: @TeaDrivenDev I definitely wouldn't recommend the second solution. I added it mostly because I think it is still clearer than the solutions in other answer that use either (||>) or <||

Answer (score 3):

In your piping, you can replace:

```
 |> apply2 valueA valueB
```

with

```
 |> (||>) (valueA, valueA)
```

So `||>` is the same as your `apply2` function but with tupled arguments.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a little trick here:

```
let useCase someValue ((valueA, valueB) as tuple) =
    someValue
    |>  ...
    |>  toMyType
    |>  myFun
    <|| tuple
```

or just

```
let useCase someValue tuple =
    ...
```